# I want to update progress bar as the response come through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to update progress bar with every single response but with this code i am getting many response at once and the last number update the progress bar.
but i am not able to get each and every response in my success function,
i also tried async:false but because of this response is getting but progress bar doesn't update only at last response progress bar update.

```
function BindTable(jsondata, tableid) {
    /*Function used to convert the JSON array to Html Table*/
    var columns = BindTableHeader(jsondata, tableid); /*Gets all the column headings of Excel*/
    //Random Id Generation 
    var random = //Some Random Number
    var i = 0;
    for (; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
        var jData = {};
        for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++) {
            var cellValue = jsondata[i][columns[colIndex]];
            // console.log(cellValue)
            jData[colIndex] = cellValue;
            if (cellValue == null)
                cellValue = "";
        }
        // console.log(jData);
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(jData);
        console.log(jsonData);
        $.ajax({
            url: URL of PHP File,
            async: true,
            timeout: 30000,
            data: {
                "data": jsonData,
                "random": random,
                "current": i,
                "last": jsondata.length
            }, //<--- Use Object
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response, textStatus, hxr) {
                $('.progress-bar').css('width', response + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', response);
                if (response != 100)
                    $('#prvalue').html(response + '% Complete')
                if (response == 100)
                    $('#prvalue').html(response + '% Complete (Success)')
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("The following error occured: " +
                    textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is Console Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htzmL.png)

```
ExcelUpload.js:140 20
ExcelUpload.js:140 24
ExcelUpload.js:140 4
ExcelUpload.js:140 8
ExcelUpload.js:140 16
ExcelUpload.js:140 12
ExcelUpload.js:140 44
ExcelUpload.js:140 36
ExcelUpload.js:140 40
ExcelUpload.js:140 28
ExcelUpload.js:140 48
ExcelUpload.js:140 32
ExcelUpload.js:140 72
ExcelUpload.js:140 68
ExcelUpload.js:140 56
ExcelUpload.js:140 64
ExcelUpload.js:140 52
ExcelUpload.js:140 60
ExcelUpload.js:140 84
ExcelUpload.js:140 96
ExcelUpload.js:140 88
ExcelUpload.js:140 80
ExcelUpload.js:140 92
ExcelUpload.js:140 76
ExcelUpload.js:140 100
```

Comment: you will get data in `success` after getting response from server, you cant use `success` for progressbar

Comment: multiple ajax requests will compete against each other when it comes to updating the status bar

Comment: See: [Monitoring progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress). Here's [an example for usage with JQuery](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5).

Comment: Count the numbers of ajaxes that will be requested I guess is jsondata.length, then use the success callback to implement a counter and refresh the data on the progress bar.I suggest to use .done and .fail to handle the counter

Comment: @gmazoni can you give me some example for this?

Comment: @MohammedMaviyaAnsari, sure, added as answer

Answer (score 0):

An example code that you can try and use with async:
You can use `.toFixed(0)` to get an integer

```
function BindTable(jsondata, tableid) {
var columns = BindTableHeader(jsondata, tableid); /*Gets all the column headings of Excel*/
//Random Id Generation 
var random = 7; //Some Random Number
var progress = 0;

for(i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
    var jData = {};
    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.length; colIndex++){
        var cellValue = jsondata[i][columns[colIndex]];
        jData[colIndex] = cellValue;
        if (cellValue == null) cellValue = "";
    }

    var jsonData = JSON.stringify(jData);
    console.log(jsonData);
    $.ajax({
        url: '', //URL of PHP File,
        async: true,
        timeout: 30000,
        data: {"data": jsonData,"random": random,"current": i,"last": jsondata.length},
        type: "POST"
    }).done(function(response, textStatus, hxr){
        progress = progress + 1;
        relative = ( progress * 100) / jsondata.length;

        $('.progress-bar').css('width', relative + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', relative);

        if (progress == jsondata.length){
            $('#prvalue').html(relative + '% Complete (Success)')
        }else{
            $('#prvalue').html(relative + '% Complete')
        }

        console.log(response, relative);

    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
    })

   }
}
```